# Nestjs - What is the right approach to have custom classes using 3rd party libraries available

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am new to NestJS and I did not find any clear instruction to do what I need to.

I wanted to build my backend using NestJS which I have never used before but only heard good things about. So the backend server I am going to build will be using a 3rd party module called ccxt from npmjs. In a normal node app, I would just create a random class for example CryptoManager, import the ccxt module and write some functions that are running on set intervals or whatever. Then I would create a controller class that instantiates an object of that CryptoManager class and from there on I can return it's responses.

But how am I supposed to do this with NestJS? What do I have to do, in order to have a custom class that is running background tasks available in other nest controllers / services and so on?

This class is just supposed to execute 3rd party (ccxt) module functions and store results in a database.But I want to be able to execute this classes methods from all points in the nestjs app (from all modules).

I hope my question is clear, if not please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need a combination of [Modules](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules) and [Providers](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers) to do this the "nest way", and then you can use dependency injection throughout your app.

Generally speaking, the way that you'd approach adding 3rd party libraries is the following:

1. Create a module to wrap your library, like "CryptoManagerModule".
2. Create a custom provider that provides the CCXT library, and add this to your `providers` array.
3. Create a service, "CryptoManagerService", and inject CCXT into the constructor.
4. Export the "CryptoManagerService" from your module, so that you can inject it into the rest of your app.
5. (Optionally) mark your module as "global", so that you only need to configure the module once in the AppModule to make it available to all other modules.

Inside `crypto-manager.module.ts`

```
import { DynamicModule, Module, Provider } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CryptoManagerService } from './crypto-manager.service';
import * as ccxt from 'ccxt';

// Add any config options you need, like API keys, etc
export interface CryptoManagerModuleOptions {
  global?: boolean;
}

export const KRAKEN_CLIENT_TOKEN = 'KRAKEN_CLIENT_TOKEN';

export class CryptoManagerModule {
  static forRoot(options: CryptoManagerModuleOptions): DynamicModule {
    // An example of injecting a single class of ccxt.  Note this is only available
    // within this module.
    const krakenProvider: Provider = {
      provide: KRAKEN_CLIENT_TOKEN,
      useValue: new ccxt.kraken(),
    };

    return {
      module: CryptoManagerModule,
      providers: [krakenProvider, CryptoManagerService],
      // Exports can be @Inject()'ed to other files, and if global
      // is set, then forRoot only needs to be called in the AppModule
      exports: [CryptoManagerService],
      global: options.global,
    };
  }
}
```

Inside `crypto-manager.service.ts`

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { KRAKEN_CLIENT_TOKEN } from './crypto-manager.module';
import { kraken } from 'ccxt';

@Injectable()
export class CryptoManagerService {
  constructor(@Inject(KRAKEN_CLIENT_TOKEN) private kraken: kraken) {}

  loadKrakenMarkets() {
    return this.kraken.loadMarkets();
  }
}
```

Inside `app.module.ts`

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { CryptoManagerModule } from './crypto-manager/crypto-manager.module';

@Module({
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
  // Make sure to call forRoot
  imports: [CryptoManagerModule.forRoot({ global: true })],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And lastly, an example of it being used inside of `app.service.ts`.  I haven't done anything special to this file, you'll just see the result logged to the console.

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CryptoManagerService } from './crypto-manager/crypto-manager.service';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(private cryptoManagerService: CryptoManagerService) {}

  getHello(): string {
    this.cryptoManagerService.loadKrakenMarkets().then(console.log);
    return 'Hello World!';
  }
}
```

Doing it this way allows you to easily mock out `kraken` when it comes time to test, allows you to pass configuration variables in the forRoot in case you want to reuse this across projects, and is a pattern that is widespread in the Nest community already.

Comment: wow thank you so much for this detailed explanation even with using the library itself. I am wondering if I  also could just declare a class with a @Injectable decorator and that class instatiates a bunch of ccxt.exchange Objects ? Would that also be a possible approach in case I would want one Manager to hold multiple exchange instances (binance, kraken etc)? 

class ExchangeManager (@Injectable annotated) holding class variables of type ccxt exchange.

Comment: In the "CryptoManagerModule" in the above example, you'd just need to add additional "providers" to the `providers` array, and `@Inject(EXCHANGE_TOKEN_HERE)` them into the service the same way that's already being done.

Comment: Yes that is what I already did and its working perfectly thanks. But I mean, whats the difference if possible at all, just creating a class like @injectable Manager that has private fields of exchange1 = new ccxt.exchangeX exchange2 = ccxt.ExchangeY

Comment: The main benefit is that you have dependency injection, so mocking out your exchanges in test becomes much simpler with Nests built in test utils.  Check this out for an example of how to override providers: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#end-to-end-testing.  Remember that you're using a custom provider, so you'd pass something like `.overrideProvider(KRAKEN_CLIENT_TOKEN)`.  Let me know if that makes sense!

Comment: Another important benefit is that you can pass configuration to the instances in the `.forRoot` method.  In this case it doesn't look like you need to, but if you need to pass an API key in the constructor you can do that directly inside `.forRoot` and then provide that instance to one or more services.

Comment: you are the man. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

I have created `nestjs-ccxt` a NestJS CCXT module wrapper for that purpose https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-ccxt

First import the `CcxtModule` as any other module

```
import { CcxtModule } from 'nestjs-ccxt';

@Module({
  imports: [CcxtModule.forRoot({ ... })],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Next in your service inject the `CcxtService` using normal constructor injection.

```
@Injectable()
export class ExchangeService {
  constructor(private ccxtService: CcxtService) {}

  async getBtcUsdtTicker() {
    const client = await this.ccxtService.getClient('binance');
    const ticker = await client.fetchTicker('BTC/USDT');
    return ticker;
  }
}
```